# EF core navigation property is null

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do a code first schemas, with 2 entities:

- request
- certificate

a request can have (optional) a certificate but a certificate always have a request (zero or one to one)

I defined the entity as followed :

```
public class Request
{
    public virtual Certificate Certificate { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long RequestID { get; set; }

    public string fieldA { get; set; }
}

public class Certificate
{
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long RequestID { get; set; }

    public string fieldB { get; set; }
}
```

And the relashionship is defined fluently in the model builder :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>().ToTable("Requests");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Certificate>().ToTable("Certificates");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
        .HasOne<Certificate>(item => item.Certificate)
        .WithOne(item => item.Request)
        .HasForeignKey<Certificate>(item => item.RequestID);
}
```

The model build correctly and I can save entities, but when I query a request which have  acertificate, the navigation property stay null :

```
Request req = await db.Requests.FirstOrDefaultAsync(item => item.RequestID == 1);
// req.Certificate is null
```

What am I missing ?

Using EntityFrameworkCore V5.0.6 and .net 5

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF core, the auto proxies (lazy loading) are disabled by default.

To enable them install package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies

```
install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies
```

and enable them in the option builder

```
optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually include the navigation properties. Try

```
Request req = await db.Requests.Include(r => r.Certificate).SingleOrDefaultAsync(item => item.RequestID == 1);
```

Also you can get rid of the virtual unless you want to enable the dreaded lazy loading (turned off by default)

Comment: If LazyLoad proxies are not enabled, you may *need* to remove the `virtual` keyword or EF Core will get gunked up and even `.Include` will not eager load the related entity. (Based on other reported weirdness /w `.Include()` "not working" in EF Core.) Personally I use LazyLoad as a failsafe, but highly recommend getting familiar with projection (`Select` / `ProjectTo`) to build more efficient queries without tripping over lazy/eager loading issues.

Comment: In the end I found out, where in EF6 lazy loading was enabled by default, here you have to enable it (with `optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies()`) and add the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` package

Comment: Yes. But don't do this.