# Entity Framework Foreign Key Object returning null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a one to one relationship between two tables using ASP.NET Core Entity Framework, `User` and `Account`.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public int Reputation { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public enum Role
    {
        User, Admin
    }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Role Type { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the data I'm seeding into them.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasData(
    new { AccountId = 1, Email = "Foo@Bar.com", Password = "Pass", Type = WebApp.Models.Account.Role.User });

modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(
    new { UserId = 1, UserName = "Scruff", CreationDate = DateTime.Now, Reputation = 0, Avatar = "Pic url" });
```

I have not changed anything from the scaffolded data that was used to create the `ApiController` but for context, here is what gets run when calling the route to return all stored users.

```
// GET: api/Users
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>>> GetUser()
{
      if (_context.User == null)
      {
          return NotFound();
      }

      return await _context.User.ToListAsync();
}
```

The context and the models migrate fine and the database doesn't complain when being updated. But when I try and access the `User` data through an `ApiController`, the `Account` property returns null.

I've looked around and encountered [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548567/foreign-key-object-returning-null-when-i-call-from-applicationdbcontext) which has the same problem as mine but still has yet to be resolved, even with adding the virtual keyword.

tl;dr

How do I enter an object into a database using Entity Framework and have it return that object and not null?

<sub>Apologies if there is something wrong with this question, I've only just recently picked up ASP.NET Core and I've just made a stack overflow account to ask this question because it's stumped me so much.</sub>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF core navigation property is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67679426/ef-core-navigation-property-is-null) The  currently accepted answer has you include a `.Include()` in your query call.

Comment: @gunr2171 Thank you for the quick response! I've appended `.Include()` to the ApiController and the object is now showing in my requests! You've got no idea how long I've spent on this, You're awesome